# Cannot redefine class on 'require_once'

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine-orm, fatal-error, codeigniter-2

**UPDATE**:

> I've abandoned CodeIgniter, and the desire to build a web interface around my database application from PHP, as there was no way of getting rid of this bug...

---

## The Exception

I get this exception:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Cannot redeclare class doctrine\orm\abstractquery in Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php on line 190

Call Stack:
    0.0007     330016   1. {main}() Q:\Digest\index.php:0
    0.0058     330800   2. require_once('Q:\Digest\lib\CodeIgniter\core\CodeIgniter.php') Q:\Digest\index.php:163
    0.2207     935856   3. call_user_func_array() Q:\Digest\lib\CodeIgniter\core\CodeIgniter.php:297
    0.2207     935904   4. Crud->index() Q:\Digest\lib\CodeIgniter\core\CodeIgniter.php:0
    0.2574    1065064   5. Crud->__getEntities() Q:\Digest\Application\controllers\crud.php:19
    0.2649    1121824   6. Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getResult() Q:\Digest\Application\controllers\crud.php:49
    0.2649    1121976   7. Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute() Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php:366
    0.2651    1121976   8. Doctrine\ORM\Query->_doExecute() Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php:528
    0.2651    1121976   9. Doctrine\ORM\Query->_parse() Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query.php:223
    0.2848    1185896  10. Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->parse() Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query.php:203
    0.3089    1238704  11. Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker->getExecutor() Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php:311
    0.3090    1239104  12. Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader->loadClass() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:0
    0.3107    1241104  13. require_once('Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\SingleSelectExecutor.php') Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:190
    0.3108    1241440  14. Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader->loadClass() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:0
```

I am using Doctrine 2.0, with the Symfony `UniversalClassLoader`, as can be seen above, to implement a data-analysis script. To view the results, I have set up a CodeIgniter project.

Here's what has me baffled with this exception: I have eliminated almost all reasonably causes, and found nothing. Tell me if I did something wrong in the elemination rounds here.

If anyone has any clue whatsoever about what might be going wrong here, please help. Should you think there is any information I've left out, also, please tell me.

Thank you.

---

### Eliminating duplicate declarations

It tells me I cannot redefine a class. I have grepped all my files, and this class is defined *only in its specific file* "Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php".

Note that initially the error was reported at the call to `require` at line 190 of the Symfony UniversalClassLoader.php, and I have changed this to `require_once` to make sure the file isn't loaded twice.

---

### Eliminating the case-sensitive filesystem

Because of the note I found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), I think it's I should share that I'm running PHP 5.3.5 on Windows 7. This *should* mean the bug/feature described below is of no influence.

> This behaviour changed in PHP 5, so
>   for example with Windows the path is
>   normalized first so that
>   C:\PROGRA~1\A.php is realized the same
>   as C:\Program Files\a.php and the file
>   is included just once.

---

### Eliminating `require` duplication

I've now gone so far as to replace every single call in every library (and my own code) to the function `require` to one to `require_once`, and the error persists unchanged. This means that I can now safely say that no call to `require` is responsible. My question remains: what is?

---

### Debugger Output

Running a debugger brings me absolutely nothing:

```
    ...
    0.4658    1274904                       -> Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker->getExecutor() Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php:311
    0.4660    1275304                         -> Logger::autoload() Q:\Digest\lib\Log4PHP\Logger.php:0
    0.4662    1275304                         -> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader->loadClass() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:0
    0.4663    1275384                           -> strripos() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:183
    0.4665    1275400                           -> substr() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:185
    0.4666    1275488                           -> strpos() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:187
    0.4667    1275520                           -> substr() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:188
    0.4668    1275672                           -> str_replace() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:189
    0.4669    1275696                           -> str_replace() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:189
    0.4671    1275656                           -> file_exists() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:190
    0.4700    1277304                           -> require_once(Q:\Digest\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\SingleSelectExecutor.php) Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:192
    0.4702    1277640                             -> Logger::autoload() Q:\Digest\lib\Log4PHP\Logger.php:0
    0.4703    1277640                             -> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader->loadClass() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:0
    0.4704    1277720                               -> strripos() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:183
    0.4706    1277736                               -> substr() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:185
    0.4707    1278280                               -> strpos() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:187
    0.4708    1278312                               -> substr() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:188
    0.4709    1278464                               -> str_replace() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:189
    0.4711    1278488                               -> str_replace() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:189
    0.4712    1278448                               -> file_exists() Q:\Digest\lib\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UniversalClassLoader.php:190
    0.5259 zu
TRACE END   [2011-03-28 11:28:00]
```

Some additional inspection tells me that the file it's loading while it crashes is  `lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\AbstractSqlExecutor.php`, or the `AbstractSqlExecutor` class... thus, something completely unrelated.

Comment: There is another instance of `include` or `require` (without `_once`) somewhere else.

Comment: Are you on Windows by any chance?

Comment: @ircmaxell: yes, I am on Windows. Could you please share why that is relevant here?

Comment: @mario: there might as well be, but as you can see the error is thrown at the invocation of `require_once`.

Comment: @Pepijn: because PHP uses a case-insensitive file system.  But that shouldn't be the problem since PHP normalizes the path anyway.  So it's likely the existence of a `require` or `include` call somewhere in the code base

Comment: @ircmaxwell: Could you explain why the exception is thrown on an invocation of `require_once`? Does this mean `require 'file.php'; require_once 'file.php';` will include the file twice?

Comment: @Pepijn: I don't believe so, but `require_once $file; require $file;` will include it twice...

Comment: @ircmaxwell: I see that; however, if you look at the top of my stack trace, you'll see the error being thrown during the invocation of `require_once`, which would mean that the file was not yet loaded, right?

Comment: @Pepijn You might try `require_once realpath($file);` instead, to ensure it is consistent.

Comment: Erm. On perhaps a side note: a class loader which continues to include/require files when the class definition is known? Isn't _that_ a bug that should be fixed?

Comment: Use a step-by-step debugger and try to put a breakpoint in the class definition, you might be able to see what happens.

Comment: @Wrikken: the bug would then (probably) be with PHP, as that is the one who calls the autoload functions.

Comment: @greg0ire: will do. I'll post back here with the results (if any).

Comment: ... the debugger brings me nothing. The last thing it reports is loading an unrelated file.

Comment: realpath might be a solution as windows is not case sensitive and that could cause the file to be imported twice

Comment: Could anyone please vote to close this question as too localized? It would fit better on code-review, not on stackoverflow - and I've since abandoned the CodeIgniter part of the project altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other possibilities I can think of (after skimming the answers proposed so far) are:

1. Maybe there is a symlink somewhere in your source tree? (I've found that require_once() isn't smart enough to know that you're importing the same file if the path looks different).
2. Maybe there's a cycle somewhere in your inclusion dependencies? (if A includes B which includes C which includes A, I've found that require_once() isn't smart enough to break the cycle).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's probably the best anwser for future readers, not because it worked. Still, thanks?

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement. I'm sorry to hear that you were unable to track down the issue, but thanks for sharing - your experience will make me think twice before using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Don't. It's a good platform (I guess), I was just trying to force it into cooperation with Doctrine, and an external class-loader.

Comment: **Attention Mac and Windows users!** Root filesystem is by default formatted as case-insensitive. Watch out for mixed case file/dir names which can be "required" multiple times because of that. Also mind the usage and retrieval of `__DIR__`, `__FILE__` and statcache after rename operations. Because of how osx works, the safest way to rename the dir to the right case is to create a new one and move all contents into it (and then clear system and php stat cache).

Answer (score 5):

Too bad you gave up.  The simple way to fix it would be to put:

```
if (!class_exists('ClassName')) {


}
```

around the file. This doesn't fix the bug, just makes the symptom go away.  Codeigniter is unfortunately not too smart about PHP5 object instantiation, and may be loading your code twice.

Comment: Don't you mean `if (! class_exists(...`?

Comment: This. Just out of curiosity, why CI and not Kohana? Kohana is a fork of CI made into a PHP5 framework.

Comment: Worked for me! ty!

Answer (score 3):

Please check if your server has APC installed. If so try to turn it off, upgrade or set apc.include_once_override setting to 0.

Comment: thank you; this did not fix it, but at least it was a fresh idea! i'm running apc (have disabled it for testing now) but the setting apc.include_once_override was at it's default (which the manual tells me is "0").

Answer (score 2):

Are you using __autoload() anywhere?  Thats the only thing I can think of, unless  you actually have the same class defined in two DIFFERENT files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have explored all of the obvious solutions, then every time I have run into this problem, it's been a caching problem, typically with APC.

If it is an apc caching problem, to fix it, add the following to your top level file at the top of the file:

```
apc_clear_cache();
```

If the problem disappears, then you know that that was the issue. In particular on shared hosting environments, if files are changing, I've found APC almost unusable, so I always add that to a top level file I can call.

PS: I've even run into situations where it seems like APC has cached the wrong file, so that it crashes when I include a file that clearly never had the class it's complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are including `UniveralClassLoader` in multiple ways, such as:

1. through `require_once`
2. use `Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;`

then the fatal error might be caused by what the compiler considers the redeclaration of the class. Remove `require_once` line if it exists and just use the second option.

Comment: The error is thrown in the file for the `UniversalClassLoader`, the component being duplicated is `AbstractQuery`. So, no. This is not what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

you may have the same class defined in two files. require_once() won't help in that case

Comment: however, grepping for "class abstractquery" without case sensitivity returns but a single file, as you can read in my question; case still open.

Answer (score 0):

```
 root
  + a.php
  + c/
     +c.php
     + b.php
```

**_ a.php _**

```
require_once 'c/b.php'; -> will work
require_once 'c/c.php'; -> will work
```

**_ c/b.php _**

```
require_once 'c.php'; -> will work too 'c/c.php'!='c.php' :(
```